# what happen to the .pem file if I submit the app using another appleID

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, pem

I have a question related to submitting iOS app to appstore.

I have a remote push notification enabled app. I have developed my app using my company appleID's provisioning profile and `.pem` file also generated using companyID's certificates.

Now my client wants to upload this app to appstore using his apple account.I know I need to generate separate provisioning profile using his ID to submit the app. But what about the `.pem` file I generated. Do I need to re generate a new one using his ID's certificates or can I use my previous `.pem` file?

Please help me in this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will need to generate a new one**

because the older one would have been linked with other developer account App, So it won't work otherwise!